# Two factor model with kalman filter for Brent oil forward curve

Tags: python, prediction, kalman-filter

I implemented a two -factor with Kalman filter by Python recently. I got the output but it is really hard to tell if I am doing right or wrong. The model itself is very complicated and it is impossible for me to put all the codes here.
I am just hoping if there is anyone who did this before can give me some idea if it is reasonable to get the following result...[Blue line is the actual forward curve and red line is what I get from Kalman filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI7nZ.png)

I am satisfied with the shape. However, while I am doing this on a rolling basis I am constantly observing my prediction somewhat higher than the actual forward curve(1-2 dollars on average). Is this a common problem using kalman filter? Anything I can do to improve the accuracy?

This question might seem ambiguous but I believe anyone who tried Kalman filter before would more or less have an idea about what I am getting here. Appreciate if anyone can provide some suggestions where I should look into regarding the output.

Comment: Your question is off-topic here, you are more likely to get useful advice on the matters of statistics and mathematical modelling on Cross Validated SE.   As far as your question goes I can only recommend you to perform hypothesis testing. When implementing mathematical models I always write suits that test that underlying assumptions hold true when they are supposed to.

Comment: Cross Validated SE is good, but I think sister site http://quant.stackexchange.com/ would be even better. It deals with financial models.